# Capture Parameters option is disabled in the application settings form of New Relic

Tags: newrelic

I want to trace HTTP params with New Relic, in the [documentation](http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/traces/collecting-custom-parameters) they talk about the *Capture parameters?* option located in the application settings form. But when I go to the page this option field is unchecked and in readonly mode.

[image: New Relic form]

So how can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the `newrelic.yml` configuration file, that way New Relic will not permit me to change settings in the settings page, instead I have to change the `capture_params` to `true` in the `newrelic.yml`.